# Specify target files from command line

Tags: rendering, command-line

Short question:

```
blender -b knob.blend -s 1 -e 2 -a -o //__targets/knob_#.png
```

Does not write to the desired files, but 0001.png, and 0002.png. I want the files __targets/knob_1.png and __targets/knob_2.png. It appears that blender ignores the target option in this case. What should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blender executes the command line options in the over they are given, so Blender sees the command to render (`-a`) and then sets the command to set the output path (`-o`). This means the output path gets set after the render has happened.

You just need to swap the order of the commands so you have:

```
blender -b knob.blend -s 1 -e 2 -o //__targets/knob_#.png -a
```

Comment: Is there a way to set a complete new harddisk path in the command line like "D:\mypath" as the target folder? This isn't working for me for any reason in Blender 2.92.